# error in manifest

Tags: android, xml

Hi I'm working on an android gps tutorial and I'm getting an error in AndroidManifest.xml.
The error is "error parsing xml: junk after document element" and its showing at the manifest start tag line. Any ideas what the problem is?? I tried deleting "xmlns......android" but that doesnt work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</View>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trail"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:versionName="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="GPSActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
          <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />       
        </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
        </manifest>
```

Comment: For future reference, an XML document can only have one root node. You are trying to use two: `<View>` and `<manifest>`. (Plenty of people have already describe what to do about it.)

Answer (score 3):

What's that View for? remove it:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trail"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:versionName="@drawable/icon" >
            <activity
                android:name="GPSActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </application>

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove that `<View>` element, just after the first line.

Explanation:
A `<View>` element belongs in a layout, not in the manifest.
Also, XML files can only have ONE top level (root) node, in this case `<manifest>`

Comment: I removed the view tags and its children but im still getting the error

Comment: Did you also remove the `</View>`?

Comment: Would you update the XML in the post, so I can see if it's right? Which editor/IDE are you using, because Eclipse should mark it as wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `View`. Your manifest doesn't need/shouldn't contain a `View`

[Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)